# ASP.NET Convert UserControl to Razor Partial View: Dealing with Property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this UserControl I want to convert into a Razor Partial View. It is the header that will be inserted into the _Layout file. Copying the HTML is pretty straight-forward ... but then how do I deal with the property?

When a page is displayed, I want to display the active menu item differently, so each page is setting MasterPage.ActiveIndex in Page_Load.

So the first part of the question is, how do I deal with the property in the Razor Partial View?

Second part of the question is, how do I deal with it in the _Layout file to provide the desired functionality?

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
<script runat="server">
    public int ActiveIndex { get; set; }
</script>
<ul class="clearfix">
    <li <%= ActiveIndex == 0 ? "class=\"active\"" : "" %>><a href="~/" runat="server">Home  </a></li>
    <li <%= ActiveIndex == 1 ? "class=\"active\"" : "" %>><a href="~/mission" runat="server">Our Mission  </a></li>
    <li <%= ActiveIndex == 2 ? "class=\"active\"" : "" %>><a href="~/books" runat="server">Books </a></li>
    <li <%= ActiveIndex == 3 ? "class=\"active\"" : "" %>><a href="~/bulk-order" runat="server">Bulk Order</a></li>
    <li <%= ActiveIndex == 4 ? "class=\"active\"" : "" %>><a href="~/book-accuracy-list" runat="server">Book Accuracy List</a></li>
    <li <%= ActiveIndex == 5 ? "class=\"active\"" : "" %>><a href="~/contact" runat="server">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use ViewData from the page to pass data to the Layout and it's sub-views.

On the page

```
@page
@{
    ViewData["ActiveIndex"] = 2;
    ViewData["Title"] = "Books";
    ViewData["Description"] = "";
    ViewData["Keywords"] = "";
}
```

In Layout, I then display the header like this

```
<partial name="_Header" model='new _HeaderModel((int?)ViewData["ActiveIndex"])' />
```

Then Header can have the strongly-typed parameter as part of its model and take it from the constructor.

```
public class _HeaderModel : PageModel {
    public int? ActiveIndex { get; set; }

    public _HeaderModel() { }

    public _HeaderModel(int? activeIndex) {
        this.ActiveIndex = activeIndex;
    }
}
```

Added a helper method

```
HtmlString ActiveTag(int index) => new HtmlString(index == ActiveIndex ? @"class=""active""" : "");
```

Then this old line

```
<li <%= ActiveIndex == 0 ? "class=\"active\"" : "" %>
```

turns into

```
<li @ActiveTag(0)>
```

Refactoring WebForms to Razor Pages requires a bit of work but always results in much less code :)